createRecord of Lightning/uiRecordApi does not work, but calling apex works
I am trying to make the first one work so I can get rid of the apex code that does the same. I dont get any errors, but the first approach to save does nowt work.
Code using the createRecord of UI api -
import { createRecord, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
let newVendorQuote = {
    apiName: 'Vendor_Quote__c',
    fields: {
        'Work_Order_ID__c': this.workorderid,
        'Vendor_Name__c': this.vendorid,
        'Vendor_Phone__c': this.vendorphone,
        'Vendor_Email__c': this.vendoremail,
        'Quote_Date__c': new Date(),
        'Status__c': 'Pending',
    }
};
        createRecord(newVendorQuote)
            .then(newVendorQuote => {
                console.log('Vendor Quote Created-' + newVendorQuote.id);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error creating Vendor Quote:', error);
            });

Code when calling an apex method-
    let newVendorQuote =
    {
        'Work_Order_ID__c': this.workorderid,
        'Vendor_Name__c': this.vendorid,
        'Vendor_Phone__c': this.vendorphone,
        'Vendor_Email__c': this.vendoremail,
        'Quote_Date__c': new Date(),
        'Status__c': 'Pending',
    };
    //Call the Apex method
    createVendorQuote({ vendorQuote: newVendorQuote })
        .then(result => {
            if (result === 'success') {
                console.log('Success');
                //console.log('Vendor quote created successfully');
            } else {
                console.error('Error creating vendor quote');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error calling Apex method:', error);
        });


You said "I don't get any errors" - but, doesn't seem you're handling rejection of the promise? Does the network tab show the call to createRecord? And any response?

@KrisGoncalves I have added the error handling code. Also I was able to see a call to createRecord on the network tab, maybe I am looking at it the right way.
